# What is the source for this idea about the deeper meaning of bowing/prostrating one's self?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, bowing-kneeling, minhag

I seem to remember hearing an idea that the significance of bowing/prostrating oneself is that a human being differs from all other elements of creation in that a human being stands erect and walks on two feet, while no other animal does that. According to this understanding, when a person bows or prostrates himself, he is showing that his very humanity and existence is owed to something higher (hopefully, to God), and he breaks his "human posture" to show that without that he is like an animal.

What is the source for this idea or something similar to it?

Comment: What about penguins' walking stance?

Comment: @Gary I wasn't asking about the accuracy of this *explanation*, I was asking for the *source*.

Comment: Well, your question started out mentioning the significance of the stance as being unique to humans, and it's not...I was just figuring if Chazal mentions creatures with their umbilical cords still attached to the earth, maybe there's something mentioned about a penguin-like animal that was similar to humans in just that "unique" way you wrote in the question.  Also, penguins do get on their bellies but not to pray(obviously), but to slide around.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Avrohom Chaim Feuer writes; "The Maharal (Derech Hachaim) provides an insight into the significance of man's upright posture. The Mishnah (Avos 3:18) teaches: "Beloved is man for he was created in God's image!" God, of course, is incorporeal and has no physical form that we can call an "image. ." When He fashioned man, however, God sought to endow the human body with one unique characteristic that would demonstrate to the rest of creation that only man represent's God's sovereignty over the world. Therefore, He made the other creatures walk or crawl or swim or fly horizontally, with the spine hunched over or bent, as a symbol of their subservience to man, who alone was Man stands created with a perfectly upright spine, a symbol of upright as he unbending, uncompromising mastery over all creatures.
Man stands upright as he recites the Amidah to symbolize that he recognizes and accepts his awesome awesome responsibility to represent God's sovereignty on earth.
Following closely the example of Abraham, man begins prayer with the proclamation that he is sovereign only through surrender. In the very first blessing, dedicated to Avraham, we bow twice, at the beginning and at the end, for only after surrender do we earn the privilege to stand upright as sovereign."[See “Shemoneh Esrei -The Amidah” published by Artscroll]

Answer (score -2):

"Kabbalicly"-wise (this idea is frequent in Ariz"l and his followers' books) the pose denotes an aspect of influence (משפיע - מקבל). Standing means משפיע while laying or leaning means מקבל.

This is pronounced in the Teffila - Krishm"A is read while sitting or laying and it signifies קבלת עול מלכות שמים, while Amida is recited while standing as Hashem is called then "ואתה קדוש יושב...", like we're influencing Hashem back.

This is also the way of teaching when the teacher stands and משפיע on the students that sit, and when one is called he stands and the teacher sits.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question. He asked for a source, not the significance of the explanation. I don’t see a single Sefer quoted here. Oh, and a Rebbe is supposed to be sitting if his Talmidim are sitting (Megillah 21a, paskened by SA YD 246:9 and Rambam Hil. Talmud Torah 4:2).

Comment: @DonielF I added a direction, I can't pinpoint a special Kabbalic book as this idea is all over all of Ariz"l's books. Your second comment is a much deeper about different views on Rav-Talmid interactions. The common one nowadays is one that I've mentioned. However from the Talmudic times there were many iterations based on different views, like כיבוד רב - Talmidim are standing and Rav sitting, all sitting (as בחי' חברים and not משפיע מקבל) and more. I would really like you to focus on the general idea of the answer instead of stinging at details.

Comment: @DonielF I disagree with your definition of "sources" - it can be a specific book and it can be a specific direction, like Talmud in general, Kabbalah, contemporary American Rabbis and more.

Comment: But if you don’t give me a source how am I supposed to look it up? “Talmud” doesn’t help anyone; “third Perek of Megillah” is at least something I can work with.

Comment: @DonielF This concept is very widely known. If you really like it,  you can try to speak to Rabbis that are familiar with Ari's works.

Comment: If it’s so widely known then you should have no problem finding a source for it. (I realize that sounds harsh - that’s not my intention at all; I just can’t think of a better way to put it.)